# Not able to resolve java.lang.NoSuchMethodError with GSON library

Tags: java, jar, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

I was trying to build a sample Retrofit Java program taken from;

https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit/SimpleService.java

I included required dependent jars (retrofit-2.0.0.jar,converter-gson-2.0.0.jar,okhttp-3.0.0-RC1.jar,okio-1.6.0.jar and gson-2.0.jar) to the build path.

I encounter the following exception while trying to run the application.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Lcom/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken;)Lcom/google/gson/TypeAdapter;
at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory.responseBodyConverter(GsonConverterFactory.java:63)
at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:325)
at retrofit2.Retrofit.responseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:308)
at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createResponseConverter(ServiceMethod.java:651)
at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:166)
at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:166)
at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:145)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.contributors(Unknown Source)
at SimpleService.main(SimpleService.java:40)
```

Am I missing any dependent jar?

I am trying to use Retrofit in standalone Java application and was testing samples to get used to it. It will be great if someone could point me to a simple sample program that demonstrates the working of Retrofit, even a sample of earlier version would be good.

Comment: I used the code as it is from the link i mentioned -https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit/SimpleService.java

Comment: I think this error is thrown when JVM can't find the in the Class Path?

Comment: So, do you think i missed adding some other required library ?

Answer (score 8):

try to add this in gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```

it works well for me :)

Comment: `gson 2.8.0` gave me `NoSuchMethodError`, downgrading to `2.6.2` worked.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some dependencies that might help you.

## GSON and Retrofit

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
```

## HTTP

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.5'
```

Try to clean your project and sync with gradle.
**Or try using the same version jar files in your project.**

Or have you replaced this line with correct value.

```
@GET("/repos/{owner}/{repo}/contributors")
```

What is the response after calling the API.
plz check the URL in the browser.

let me know if issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final RETROFIT_VERSION = '2.0.0'
final OKHTTP_VERSION = '3.2.0'

compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$RETROFIT_VERSION"
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$RETROFIT_VERSION"
compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$OKHTTP_VERSION"
compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:$OKHTTP_VERSION"

compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
```

Comment: I tired using the jar version as you suggested but i still get the below error. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.Gson.newJsonReader(Ljava/io/Reader;)Lcom/google/gson/stream/JsonReader;
 at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:35)

Comment: My current class path has below jars.                                                                     
 okio-1.6.0.jar
 retrofit-2.0.0.jar
 okhttp-3.2.0.jar
 okhttp-urlconnection-3.2.0.jar
 gson-2.4.jar
 converter-gson-2.0.0.jar

Comment: Remove `jar` file and what he say to your grable

Comment: I don't use gradle  or even Maven, i use ANT for my project which is a  windows standalone application. I am not sure you could do this using ANT.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I used the Alfresco Rest API in my JEE Application
I solved the problem by adding these Maven dependencies

```
<properties>
    <retrofit.version>2.1.0</retrofit.version>
    <okhttp.version>3.4.1</okhttp.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
        <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
        <version>${retrofit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
        <artifactId>converter-gson</artifactId>
        <version>${retrofit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
        <artifactId>adapter-rxjava</artifactId>
        <version>${retrofit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
         <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
         <version>${okhttp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
         <artifactId>logging-interceptor</artifactId>
         <version>${okhttp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Or you can add the correct Libraries (Jar files) in your build path if your are not using maven

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, yes, but I struggled with this for a week.  Wanted to post the solution that worked for me.

If you get this issue it could be from the existing crawler being FUBAR. As a workaround you can go back to the previous version of the crawler by opting out of the newly released one.

Here's how to opt-out:

Sign in to your Play Console. Select an app. Select Release management > Pre-launch report > Settings. In the “Pre-launch report version” section, move the Opt-out switch to the right until it turns blue. After this, the launch reports appear correctly again.